# Can we check if the network connection is metered or not?

Tags: go, network-programming

I am new to golang and still learning things. Could you please let me know if there is a way we can check if the network connection is metered or not in golang?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is a "metered network connection"?

Comment: @Volker, usually that means "charged with monetary payment per some unit of data transferred". I'd interpret the term in this context.

Comment: Disregarding the Go aspect for the moment, how would you establish such a thing?

Comment: Go is a general-purpose programming language, so it does not have any notion of "metered network connection". This information requires interacting with certain APIs of the underlying OS, which are not in any way standardized. Hence 1) No, not in plain Go; 2) Yes, with the help of external packages or using system calls, but this highly depends on the context: "what OS" is the first question to answer, but not the sole one, usually.

Comment: For instance, on a "typical desktop" Linux-based OS these days network connectivity is handled by NetworkManager, and it exposed a D-Bus API which can be used to ask the device handling current connection whether it's metered or not (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560217/43156)). So, to use it, you'd need one of [the packages supporting D-Bus](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=dbus). …

Comment: …Win32 API provides the [`NetworkListManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nn-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager) which can be used via [`go-ole`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-ole/go-ole). I have no idea what APIs should be used on Mac OS X and Android, or Unix-like OSes based on kernels other than Linux. Basically, the above is more to demonstrate that there are no standard solutions for what you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much @kostix. It gives me some ideas to explore.

Comment: By the way, i need to check for Windows, Linux, Mac OS.